# svg mask does not work under Firefox and IE

Tags: html, css, svg

I use svg icons with mask-image which does work under Chrome and Safari very well but does not under Firefox and IE or Edge.

```
    <div class="btn"></div>

    .btn
        position: absolute
        top: 20px
        left: 20px
        background-repeat: no-repeat
        height: 50px
        width: 50px
        background-color: blue
        mask-image: url(arrow-down-light.svg)
```

Many thanky for all your suggestions!

Comment: are you testing with Firefox 53 or above?

Comment: Indeed, I believe FF54 now supports masks - https://hacks.mozilla.org/2017/06/css-shapes-clipping-and-masking/